# Trying to connect the loopback mongodb connector with AWS DocumentDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, openshift, loopbackjs, aws-documentdb

So hey I've been trying to edit the datasource.json file with the mongodb loopback connector to connect to AWS DocumentDB with TLS Enabled. We're doing a connection from OpenShift (deployed on AWS) and with an AWS DocumentDB instance. VPC Peering has been successfully enabled and I can connect from just a mongo pod. Currently I've been trying to use IBM App Connect Enterprise/IBM Integration Bus using their LoopBack Request Node. There's a public key certificate at https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem but I don't think it's being picked up correctly from the datasource.json file below -

```
{"mongodb" : {
"user":"user",
"password":"pw",
"host":"docdbURL",
"port":"27017",
"url":false,
"database": "sample_database",
"name": "mongodb",
"useNewUrlParser": true,
"ssl": true,
"sslValidate": true,
"checkServerIdentity": false,
"sslCA": "/pathTo/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem",
"connector": "mongodb"
```

}}

Comment: Are you able to connect to your DocumentDB instance from the MongoDB shell with the public key cert?

Comment: @meet-bhagdev Sorry for the late reply, yes I can. I can Mongo Shell into the DocumentDB instance from the pod with the certificate in the folder where I connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically timeouts are a result of a network issue such as the client being in a different VPC, different region, or an issue with the security group. For more on troubleshooting network connectivity, please see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.html

If you don't think it is network connectivity, and think it is related to your TLS connection, then it would be good to verify by turning off TLS and seeing if you can connect successfully without TLS enabled from your application. To disable TLS, please see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/security.encryption.ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding Certificate Path in JSON file won't be useful (It will not read actual content of file)
Instead you can use 'datasource.{environment}.js' file to read the content of certificate and add it in configuration.
In following way you can use datasource.local.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require("path");
var ca = [fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem"))];

var datasourc ={
    mongodb : {
      user:"user",
      password:"pw",
      host:"docdbURL",
      port:"27017",
      url:false,
      database: "sample_database",
      name: "mongodb",
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      ssl: true,
      sslValidate: true,
      checkServerIdentity: false,
      sslCA: ca,
      connector: "mongodb"
    }
};
module.exports = datasourc;
```

Use following loopback documentation link for reference
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Environment-specific-configuration.html